# Using Application Secrets like API keys inside of Nunit unit tests?

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I have an Azure function running .NET 8 inside of Visual Studio 2022 in  that I run a variety of Integration tests using NUnit 4.0.1. A few of these methods that I am testing require API keys and other strings that are sensitive to the Function.

Inside of the Function this integration layer in which I am testing is instanced via dependency injection in the Function in which it passes through the API keys. With these API keys being stored as Enviroment variables inside of the Function.

Currently these Unit tests run locally on my machine. But I would potentially add this to CI/CD in the future.

How does I best handle these values inside of a Unit test project running NUnit?

Thank you and let me know if I can provide any more information

Comment: Do your tests need *real* API keys (that are capable of making API calls) or just "there's something configured"? (I'd expect genuine *unit* tests to fake out remote APIs. Of course, you could have integration tests written in NUnit too...)

Comment: Yes it needs real API keys as I am testing an integration layer that I require the keys for this class to be able to be initialized as the integration is used in multiple places. When this class gets initialized the class using it gets the keys from the Environment variables.

Comment: Right - I'd suggest clarifying that in the question then (and I'd personally refer to those as integration tests rather than unit tests). Next, it's worth going into more details about what you're looking for. I would *at least* provide another way of configuring the code to use specified API keys rather than environment variables... but you should give details about where you want these unit tests to run, and what level of security is already in place in those environments.

Comment: Question has been updated with clarification in what I am aiming to do.

Comment: Well, this then becomes a question of which CI/CD system... most have ways of managing secrets. You could even stick with the existing environment variable approach if you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact that you're going to integrate this to CI/CD pipeline, I'd suggest utilizing Azure `KeyVault`/`AppConfiguration` will ensure the secure aspects in you API keys. Or else if you have environment variables in place, you can use that as well.